# Are products unindexed after some time on Google Vision API Product Search?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I use Google Vision API Product Search for a while now and realized some entire product sets get unindexed after some time...

These are same product sets get indexed without error, but after some time if not queried, product sets get unindexed (their index time is reset to 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

If I query them after some days, I get a `no product found` response.
After being queried, the product set gets reindexed after an hour (1 or 2 cycles).

Is it a normal feature of the API? if so where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 0):

The indexing is automatic. If your set has the 0 timestamp, it hasn't been indexed yet.
You could verify that you have added the products by listing all of them. If the product set has no images or missing one image, it won't be indexed.

> The Product Search index of products is updated approximately every 30
> minutes. When images are added or deleted, the change won't be
> reflected in your Product Search responses until the index is next
> updated.

Another option to make sure that indexing is completed successfully is to check the index time field of the product set.
The index time indicates the time at which the last index was. If this is increasing, that means it's still up to date.

You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-reference-images) and more information about [productSet](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.productSets#ProductSet).

**Another possibility is that you’re hitting some type of [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/quotas) that affects the indexation, like quota limits.**

I don’t have access into your project if this issue is affecting you drastically and persists, you could open a [support case](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en) and a colleague will look deeply into your project to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: As I mentioned very clearly in my question, my product set USED TO BE indexed and worked perfectly fine. However, after a certain time without querying it, the index of the product set becomes 0 again. Someone else on the cloud-vision-discuss group had the same issue but didn't receive any answer... thank you for your help

Comment: @Côme Schaeffer I updated my answer.

Comment: I believe that I am not exceeding any quota... I will open a support case then, thanks

Comment: @Côme Schaeffer If this information help you or guide you to solve your issue. You can consider voting. This indicates to the wider community that this information help you to found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Your answer did not add anything more than what was already said on the Google Group, so I am not upvoting it...

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I seem to have the same issue.